# Write a unique list of specified entities to an output files from an input file

Tags: python

I have an input text file in the format below that contains user names and programing languages. I want to write a list of only unique programing languages to an output file. I am thinking I need to generate a list of all programing languages, and then use set to create a unique list of programing languages, then finally write that to an output file.
Any feedback as to how to update the code would be most welcomed. Thanks

**Input File:**

```
name: languages
Smith, John J : VBA, 
Jones, Brian Jack : Basic, assm, shell
Page, Jimmy : matlab, autocad, python
Plant, Robert P : C, C++, SQL, 
Burton, Eric : matlab, VBA, SQL, 
Frampton, Peter: VBA, basic SQL, pascal, matlab
Jagger, Mick L : 
Anderson, Ian M : C++
Joplin, Janis J : SQL, 
Morrison, Jim : C, VB, SQL, SAS, 
Hendrix, Jimmy M : python
Chang, Jackie : C,
```

**Program:**

```
#read file into variable line
f = open('languages_1.txt')

while True:
    list1 =[]
    list2 =[]
    # print (f)

    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    # print('Output 1', line)    

    #convert all text to lower case
    line = line.lower()
    # print('Output 2', line)

    #remove white spaces
    line = line.replace(" ", "")
    # print('Output 3', line)

    #replace commas with new line value
    line = line.strip()
    # print('Output 4', line)

    #partition each entry by :
    head, sep, tail = line.partition(':')
    # print('Output 5', line)

    #remove names and stip leading white space
    line2 = tail
    # print('Output 6', line) 

    # split each entry by ,
    list1 =line2.split(',')
    print(list1)


# the_set = set(list1)
# print(the_set)    

# outfile = open('language_list1.txt', 'w')
# outfile.write("this is line: %i\n"%i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I updated the code and it functions as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You just need to create the set before the while loop (`the_set = set()`), then update it in the while loop (`the_set.update(list1)`), and that will get you a functioning program.

Beyond that, there are several things you can do to clean it up.  First `list2` looks unused.  Second, `list1` doesn't need to be set to `[]` as the first line in the loop, since that empty list is just discarded and replaced with the results of the split on the line `list1 =line2.split(',')`.

From there, the next change I would make would be to change the structure:

```
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
         break
    # do stuff
```

with the more pythonic:

```
for line in f:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to split twice and update:

```
with open("Names.txt") as f:
    unique = set()
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip().rsplit(":",1)[-1].replace(" ","")
        unique.update(line.split(","))
    print(unique)

set(['', 'assm', 'VBA', 'shell', 'autocad', 'python', 'SQL', 'C', 'C++', 'languages', 'VB', 'pascal', 'matlab', 'Basic', 'SAS', 'basicSQL'])
```

`rsplit(":",1)[-1]` splits on `":"` and gets the last element which are the  programming languages, then  `.split(",")` splits them into individual words.

You just need to loop over the file object, python will end the loop when the EOF is reached.
Also using `with` to open your files is the best way to go as it will automatically close them for you.

Comment: I haven't used 'with, but I will be .Thank you for the information, your solution is very concise .